# How to generate lh6.googleusercontent.com/[LONG_CODE], image url of a drive image, using it's doc id

Tags: android, lua, google-drive-api, coronasdk, imagedownload

So I'm trying to obtain a direct display url to images in a drive, using their document id's, like the url's that end in ".jpeg" and such, that only display the image, then use this link within my code to download the image.

I found a url that was supposed to do that:

`https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=[file_Id]`

but once this url is typed in and enter is clicked, it changes to a long url beginning with `lh6.googleusercontent.com`, this url is what displays the image the way I want when typed into a browser.

The problem now is, in my code, when I try to use `https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=[file_Id]` it doesn't work but when I use the long code beginning with `lh6.googleusercontent.com`, it downloads perfectly, so I want to know how to generate this `lh6.googleusercontent.com` url from the doc id, within my code, so I can use that as the download link.

The app I'm trying to make is Android, and I'm making it using Corona with lua.
Thanks

Comment: It sounds a bit like you are trying to use Google Drive in a way it was not intended to be used.  Google Drive is for personal file storage -- it isn't for images you embed in your app ("assets").  For that, you use Google Cloud Storage, Amazon S3, etc.  If that isn't what you're doing, please clarify.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I already have the app set up in a way that it could download images from the drive to display in the app but my current method is far too slow and If I could find a way to figure this out, t would make the process faster but if it's not intended to be used this way, I'll look up the other options you mentioned

Comment: As far as I can tell, these URLs can't be derived or "generated" -- they have to actually be fetched from the service, itself, and of course you need to be an authenticated user in order to do so.  Google Drive is a storage and "sharing" service, but you appear to be using it as a "hosting" service.  At some point, you may find that Google calls foul because you're using the product outside of its intended application.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i'm not really trying to host things, just get 1 or 2 images from my drive but thanks for the help